# How to create a query with primary/secondary language code

Tags: abap, opensql

Please tell me how to do so: 
there is a table MAKT. I have MAKTX in the French language (SPRAS='FR'), but if French language isn't here, then need to display MAKTX in English. How to do it correctly?

```
 IF MAKT-SPRAS='FR'.
    SELECT SINGLE MAKT-MAKTX FROM MAKT WHERE SPRAS='FR'.
 ELSE.
    SELECT SINGLE MAKT-MAKTX FROM MAKT WHERE SPRAS='EN'.
 ENDIF.
```

Comment: In this situation you are looking for a single description, not getting descriptions for a table of materials, correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can get with order by.

```
select * from MAKT where SPRAS = 'FR' or SPRAS = 'EN' order by SPRAS descending.
  exit.
endselect.
```

Comment: Thanks, Mkysoft! In this case, the information is displayed all in a row. And it is necessary only 'FR'. If 'FR' is not, then only 'EN'. How to do so?

Comment: @Callisto above query getting all translation order by language. So FR is always on top if it is there. exit command stop loop in table (we cannot use select single with order by). You can remove * and add what you want. Also you need MATNR filter I think.

Comment: What is the need of `SELECT...ENDSELECT` here? It perfectly can be written with `SELECT SINGLE`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the SELECT .. ENDSELECT is essential - there's no real performance issue because the poster asked for a select single. When you do the order by it will return 'FR' then 'EN' if both exist or just 'EN' - the 'EXIT' jumps out of the loop after one record - so you get 'FR' if it exists or 'EN' if not.

Comment: @Suncatcher Apparently you can't `ORDER BY ...` in `SELECT SINGLE`.

Comment: @LPK, yep, correct. Also, compound `OR` condition should be wrapped into parenthesis otherwise it will fetch bunch of irrelevant rows. It's of no importance here because of `EXIT`, but just in case of...

Answer (score 1):

I personally do not recommend using `SELECT...EXIT ENDSELECT.` with `ORDER BY` in this case!

Here is a way that is much more concise and gives full control of what you want to do to the database:

```
DATA: ls_makt TYPE makt.

SELECT SINGLE * FROM makt
  INTO ls_makt
  WHERE matnr EQ <your-matnr>
    AND ( spras EQ 'FR' 
          OR ( spras EQ 'EN'
               AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM makt
                                WHERE matnr EQ <your-matnr>
                                AND   spras EQ 'FR' ) ) ).
```

This will select your material text in French or in English, but just if the French text does not exist.

EDITED according to the first comment. You were right, ... SINGLE... was missing in the SELECT statement.

Comment: I believe this to be a better approach than the one above, but I also believe it can be enhanced by performing `SELECT SINGLE * FROM makt INTO ls_makt` where `ls_makt` is defined as a line of the `MAKT` table. I'm not sure this will activate the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic where clause in ABAP like this.

```
 DATA wherecond TYPE String.

 IF MAKT-SPRAS='FR'.
    CONCATENATE 'SPRAS = ''' FR '''' INTO wherecond.
 ELSE.
     CONCATENATE 'SPRAS = ''' EN '''' INTO wherecond.
 ENDIF.

 SELECT SINGLE MAKT-MAKTX FROM MAKT WHERE (wherecond).
```